# How to access low-level sqlite3 handle from QSqlDatabase?

Tags: qt, sqlite

Is it possible to obtain a low-level `sqlite3*` handle from an opened QSqlDatabase with QSQLite driver?

I need to call some low-level sqlite3-functions on it, in order to install a custom SQL function.

Update: Found the solution:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(sqlite3*)

sqlite* sqlite_handle = database.driver()->handle().value<sqlite3*>();
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case (qt5, sqlite3) you must do it this way. If you don't include `Q_DECLARE_OPAQUE_POINTER()` you get an error.

```
Q_DECLARE_OPAQUE_POINTER(sqlite3*)
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(sqlite3*)

sqlite* sqlite_handle = database.driver()->handle().value<sqlite3*>();
```

Answer (score 3):

QSqlDriver has a [`handle()` method](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qsqldriver.html#handle) which will return the low level database handle wrapped in a QVariant. You can get this driver [via your QSqlDatabase](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qsqldatabase.html#driver).